# httpd.conf (ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse)

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, httpd.conf, proxypass

I would like to ask what is the difference between the following configurations below.

application original URL/location: http://localhost:8080/MyServerApp/App_1

1st set-up/configuration

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /app http://localhost:8080/MyServerApp/App_1 retry=0
ProxyPassReverse /app http://localhost:8080/MyServerApp/App_1
```

2nd set-up/configuration

```
<Location /app >
   ProxyPass          http://localhost:8080/MyServerApp/App_1
   ProxyPassReverse   http://localhost:8080/MyServerApp/App_1
</Location>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different syntaxes are functionally identical. As stated in the [manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) :

> When used inside a `<Location>` section, the first argument (of the directive syntax  `ProxyPass [PATH] !|URL`) is omitted and the local directory is obtained from the `<Location>`.